# Network is unreachable in ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, ubuntu-gnome, tty

When I’d try to ping 8.8.8.8 I’ll face face this:

> network unreachable

And when I run bellow command I’ll face to an empty result:

```
Sudo ip route
```

What should I do?
My ubuntu release is 19.04

Comment: @user535733 19.04 and it was ok. I would downgrade it.

Comment: @user535733 It worked well.

Comment: What is the complete output of `dhclient`?

Comment: @user535733 r8169: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw (-2)

Comment: There are three possible failures: If the dhcp server failed to assign an IP address, if the `dhclient` is missing or failed to requies a dchp address, or if the hardware driver for the network connection failed to load. Your output seems to indicate the third.

Comment: Server or Desktop installation? Wireless or wired connection? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d reconfigure my firmware and fix this error by users help:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firmware-linux-free
```