# network is unreachable in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. I wanted to use Python 3.7 so I installed it and uninstalled Python 3.6, but it was a big mistake because now all my programs are acting weirdly.

I restarted my PC now I only running with the terminal. I tried `sudo apt-get update` but it fails to reach the Ubuntu server.

I tried with ping to 8.8.8.8 and it says `Connection: Network is unreachable`.

I search around on this forum, but there seems to be no answer for me until now. Here is the error screen.

[image: error screen]

What I have tried:

`ifconfig` => That command is not supported. Follow the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/415023/connect-network-is-unreachable-ping)

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure firmware-linux-free` => firmware-linux-free not installed. Follow the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155857/network-is-unreachable-in-ubuntu)

I tried to clean the NetworkConfig as the answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217369/clear-apt-get-list)

I reached to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) however, I don't find any repo in the list so I don't comment anything.

Do you have any idea how to get the network back? After that, I will try to reinstall other software.

Comment: One easy solution is to reinstall Ubuntu or to install a newer release of Ubuntu (like the newly-released 20.04).  Breaking your system by replacing a critical component is a classic new-user mistake. The safe (and recommended) way to get newer software is to use a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I reinstall the Ubuntu and everything is working okay now. I need spend time to install other programming tools as it is better way. Will be tried the latest version later

Comment: Hello @karel, It is not the answer for my question. The answer is how to restore the python with apt with network is normal. But my problem is `network is unreachable`.

Comment: I already try to reinstall all the missing package when I realize I make the mistake. But I get the error as the question title. You can see the image, I try with `apt` but it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Hey @karel, I'm not sure this answer can solve my problem as I re-install the Ubuntu long time ago.

Comment: I have a great faith in Ubuntu ( and Linux in general )... Can't believe someone can give "reinstall ubuntu" as "one easy solution" to get network back. I just install my Bionic and got this same error just after first boot.